# Bootstrap tabpanel which tab is selected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap tabpanel like this:

```
<div class="row spiff_tabs_body">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs spiff_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/delayedspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Potential Spiff</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="FormGet('dashboard/instantspiff', 'delayedspiff')">Instant Spiff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="delayedspiff"></div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="instantspiff"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using javascript I need to figure out which tab the user is on.  I'm not really sure how to  do this.  I've read a lot about selecting the active tab, but I can't really find out how to check which tab the user has selected.

Updated:

I forgot to mention I need to be able to check in a conditional if statement which tab is selected and then do something based on which tab is active.

I need to do something like this:

```
<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // here is the new selected tab id
    var selectedTabId = e.target.id;
});

var id = $('.tab-content .active').attr('id');
if (id == "instantspiff") {
    alert("instantspiff");
}
else {
    alert("delayedspiff");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can get the id of the active tab `$('.tab-content .active').attr('id');` if you are using jquery

Comment: @SherifAhmed See my update in my question.  I somehow need to use the tab id in a if statement.  Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check this

```
var id = $('.tab-content .active').attr('id');
if(id == "delayedspiff") {
    alert("delayedspiff");
}
else {
    alert("instantspiff");
}
```

when they click on a tab add this

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    // here is the new selected tab id
    var selectedTabId = e.target.id;
});
```

Comment: SherifAhmed This only works when the page loads.  How can I get it to work when they click on the tabs?

Comment: Ok I added the code to my page, but now it does nothing?  I updated my question to show you how I have the code.  I'm guessing I just don't understand.  Do I need to add it to an onclick event?

Comment: Ok! I got it!  Thank you so much